# What does this "ansible -m ping all" mean?

Tags: ansible

```
ansible -m ping all
```

Why am I getting the same warnings and Errors when I tried running my Playbook? (starfish.yml)

So, that means: My Playbook is Right? But something important is Not. What is that?
Please Help...Thank You.

With Hope,
Prabhakaran

The following are the Warnings and Errors:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init_.py:44: CyptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.
     from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with yaml plugin: We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: No JSON object could be decoded Syntax Error while loading YAML. expected '<document start>', but found '[' The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/hosts': line 4, column 1, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem. The offending line appears to be: ] [starfish] ^ here
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with ini plugin: need more than 2 values to upack
[WARNING]:  Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]:  No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Comment: The messages clearly points to your `/etc/ansible/hosts` file as having a problem. Doesn't it make sense to include it in the body of your question? Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Sir,  I am sincerely sorry to not able understand your comment. Especially the following statement:  code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs. Please consider and Kindly do the needfut. With Hope: Prabhakaran

Comment: Edit your question (Q) to include your `/etc/ansible/hosts` files. When you copy/paste that file into your question, use your mouse cursor to highlight that text and then click on the `{}` tool in the Edit Menu. This will give the correct formatting. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Sir. Thanks for your comment. Actually I am using CentOS 7 Minimal Edition (Command Line Only). I cannot do a Copy and Paste. Anyways, I have typed and tried the following code command:
ansible -m ping /etc/ansible/hosts starfish.yml

The results looks like a Help Document... You know..
Connection Options and all other Commands and Descriptions...

Comment: Sorry I won't be able to help further on this. You'll need to find a way to include the contents of `/etc/ansible/hosts` into the body of your Q above, `ftp` from your CentOS to your Windows/Mac machine maybe? Did the answer below provide any help? You should leave a comment to that person to let them know. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to follow this doc https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html to build your ansible inventory.